On induced charges of different shapes
Let's begin with a straightforward scenario: imagine a ball carrying a charge of $q$, surrounded by a grounded conducting sphere that envelops it. In this setup, there's no doubt that the sphere will have an induced charge of $−q$.
Now, consider replacing the sphere with an infinite grounded conducting plane. My intuition is, the induced charge would remain $−q$. However, if we further substitute this infinite plane with a grounded conducting ball positioned some distance away from the originally charged ball, it becomes less straightforward. Here, I suspect that the induced charge would no longer be precisely $−q$. To illustrate, as the radius of this grounded ball approaches zero, the internal energy tends to infinity, suggesting a deviation from the $−q$ induced charge scenario.
There exists a vast array of intermediary shapes between these extremes—such as an infinite half plane—that introduce complexities into determining the exact induced charge. This leads to my question: what specific shape of a conductor can guarantee that the induced charge will be $−q$?

It follows from Gauss Law that any grounded conductor of any shape, enclosing the charged sphere will get induced with -q charge. Same goes for Infinite plane. For any other shape which is finite or semi-infinite and not enclosing the charged sphere, will get induced with charge of lesser magnitude.

@Param_1729 "enclosing by infinite plane" is not well defined. Consider a ball carrying a charge of $q$, then the flux through an infinite plane with some distance is only a half predicted by gauss law. Say the ball is at $(0,0,0)$ and plane to be $x=1$, one need to add another plane $x=-1$ to capture all flux.
